# HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode() weird behaviour

Tags: java, sockets, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    private static class UserAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

        Authenticator.setDefault(new UserAuthenticator());
        //CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER);
        //CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://123.123.123.123");
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Connection is still close

            int code = httpCon.getResponseCode(); //Instead of generating a single request, this generates a bunch of them 
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

The getResponceCode() method generates multiple requests to the server instead of a single as stated at the JavaDocs. I chained JVM with BurpSuite, which is a very good proxy, so I'm pretty sure it is not a proxy problem or something similar.

I would really appreciate if anybody could help me and explain me *why this happens*.

I sould also mention that if you enable cookies manager it just generates two requests. The first gets 401 response code and the second one gets 299 response code (which means the second request was successful) and then stops. *Why this is happening?*

Also, on the first request no authentication credentials are sent but they are sent on every request after the second. *Why this is happening?*

**[EDIT]**

I'm posting the headers of the communication:

Without using cookies:

Request1 :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_144
Host: 192.168.1.1
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: close
```

Response1 :

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 11:56:36 GMT
Server: Boa/0.94.13
Connection: close
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="H108NS"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=4ee8135d;
```

Request2 :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_144
Host: 192.168.1.1
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Connection: close
```

Response2 :

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 11:56:38 GMT
Server: Boa/0.94.13
Connection: close
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="H108NS"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=2ac98489;
```

Request2 and Response2 are repeated for about 10-20 times.
This was without cookies. Trying with cookies this happens:

Request1 with cookies:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_144
Host: 192.168.1.1
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: close
```

Response1 with cookies:

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 12:02:01 GMT
Server: Boa/0.94.13
Connection: close
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="H108NS"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=4b33e52e;
```

Request2 with cookies:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_144
Host: 192.168.1.1
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Cookie: SESSIONID=4b33e52e
Connection: close
```

Response2 with cookies:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: would be nice to see some HTTP logs.

Comment: @Gimby Check post edit!

Comment: Logs are text which can easily be embedded in the question, and then I get a screencast where someone clicks through everything with lightning speed :/

Comment: @Gimby check edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is how HTTP with authentication is working. The first request is happening without credentials. The response of the server with status code 401 tells the client that authentication is required and also contains the information what authentication mechanisms are supported/accepted. The client uses this information to create a subsequent request including the authentication.

Dependent on the authentication mechanism you might have seen more than two requests, e.g. NTLM leads to a couple of request-response-cycles. In your case I assume that BASIC or DIGEST Authentication did happen.

Because HTTP is stateless, all requests need authentication informations, that's why all subsequent requests also contain the credentials. This is mechanism-dependent, so e.g. again with NTLM the details within the request look different.

To see what is happening you might just start a network analyser like Wireshark where you can see the requests and responses of each erquest/response-cycle.

With the traces you provided it seems that the server needs your the cookie-value to keep track of your session after authentication. That's why you get an "401 Unauthorized" as response.

Comment: Yes, indeed type of Authentication is Basic. But why it generates so much requests when it gets 401 response code, while at the same time it is providing the credentials?

Comment: It's not sending any credentials on the first request because the client doesn't know the type of authentication available.

Comment: Ok, I got what you are talking about, but why after failing to get authentication at the second request it generates a bunch of them?

Comment: Question is why it generates all these subsequent requests after failing to authenticate?

Comment: You never mentioned a "failed authentication" in your question, only a successful one.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out my JVM was using sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection ,as an implementation of the java.net.HttpURLConnection, which is a class full of bugs. You maybe want to take a look at this [post](http://koenserneels.blogspot.gr/2016/01/pola-and-httpurlconnection.html) which I found helpful.

Actually there is a way to circumvent this problem but only in case of sending **POST** requests. This is by setting the JVM property `sun.net.http.retryPost` to `false`. This can be done through `System.setProperty("sun.net.http.retryPost", "false")`

In my case I couldn't manage to find any fix to my problem, but anyways it is just some extra GET requests, that jsut increases your traffic a little bit and it is not so disastrous as it would be with some POST requests repeating.

PS : If anybody has some suggests/solutions I 'll be happy to hear them.